# Check if a substring is present in a string variable that may be set to None

Tags: python, string

I have a string named brand that can be `None` or contain a value. How can I search for a substring within it when it is `None`?

By putting an additional if-statement to check if the brand is for `None` before searching the substring works, but is there a better way?

```
### When the string brand contains a value ###
brand = "Vans.com"
if("Vans" in brand):
   print("Y")
else:
   print("N")
# output - Y


### When the string brand is None ###
brand = None
if("Vans" in brand):
   print("Y")
else:
   print("N")
# output - TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable. 


### After putting  an additional check ###
brand = None
if (brand is not None):
  if("Vans" in brand):
     print("Y")
  else:
     print("N")

# No output
```

Comment: You might consider replacing `None` with an empty string when appropriate (either immediately when you would have assigned `None`, or prior to the code that expects `brand` to be a `str` value).

Comment: `if brand and "Vans" in brand` would do

Comment: "I have a string named brand that can be None or contain a value." so, that is actually a contradiction. You either have a `str` object or the `None` object. I guess this might seem pedantic, but pedantry is the name of the game in programming

Comment: anyay, there are various ways to make the syntax more ergonomic. But perhaps the better question is, why can this variable take the `None` value to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `and` operator to avoid nesting `if` statements.

```py
if brand and "Vans" in brand:
```

Alternatively, it may work to replace `None` with an empty string before attempting to use the string.

```py
brand = brand or ''
if "Vans" in brand:
```

Answer (score 0):

Also `try/except` would work

```
try:
   print('y' if 'vans' in brand else 'n')
except:
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting `brand` to a string object.

```
brand = None

match = "Vans"
if match in str(brand):
    print('Y')
else:
    print('N')
```

Eventually, take advantage of `str`-methods such as `str.find`

```
brand = None

match = "Vans"
if str(brand).find(match):
    print('N')
else:
    print('Y')
```